# How to replace timestamp across the columns using pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, datetime

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
 'subject_id':[1,1,2,2],
 'time_1':['2173/04/11 12:35:00','2173/04/12 12:50:00','2173/04/11 12:59:00','2173/04/12 13:14:00'],
 'time_2':['2173/04/12 16:35:00','2173/04/13 18:50:00','2173/04/13 22:59:00','2173/04/21 17:14:00'],
  'val' :[5,5,40,40],
  'iid' :[12,12,12,12]   
 })
df['time_1'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time_1'])
df['time_2'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time_2'])
df['day'] = df['time_1'].dt.day
```

Currently my dataframe looks like as shown below

[image]

I would like to replace the timestamp in `time_1` column to `00:00:00` and `time_2` column to `23:59:00`

This is what I tried but it doesn't work

```
df.groupby(df['subject_id'])['time_1'].apply(lambda x: pd.datetime.strftime(x, "%H:%M:%S") == "00:00:00")   #approach 1

df.groupby(df['subject_id'])['time_1'].apply(lambda x: pd.pd.Timestamp(hour = '00', second = '00')) #approach 2
```

I expect my output dataframe to be like as shown below

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I pandas if all datetimes have `00:00:00` times in same column then not display it.

Use [`Series.dt.floor`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.floor.html) or [`Series.str.normalize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.normalize.html) for remove times and for second add `DateOffset`:

```
df['time_1'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time_1']).dt.floor('d')
#alternative
#df['time_1'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time_1']).dt.normalize()
df['time_2']=pd.to_datetime(df['time_2']).dt.floor('d') + pd.DateOffset(hours=23, minutes=59)
df['day'] = df['time_1'].dt.day

print (df)
   subject_id     time_1              time_2  val  iid  day
0           1 2173-04-11 2173-04-12 23:59:00    5   12   11
1           1 2173-04-12 2173-04-13 23:59:00    5   12   12
2           2 2173-04-11 2173-04-13 23:59:00   40   12   11
3           2 2173-04-12 2173-04-21 23:59:00   40   12   12
```

Comment: Actually I see that `00:00:00` isn't visible. Is it possible to make them viewable? Or is it like when I export to csv, I will see them?. Upvoted

Comment: @SSMK - Just tested, in excel are added `00:00:00`